# Kendo Scheduler, closing event reset data

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to create a scheduler with Kendo. But I meet some bugs.

And the biggest is the following.

When I want to edit a task, I can change all values if I validate my modification, it changes the datasource correctly. Then, if I open it again, all data appears properly. BUT if I click on the cancel event ( the cross button or the cancel button ), the datasource of the current item come back to initial value and ignore the modifications I made before.

I tried a lot of solutions, even while removing all of my code, but the problem was still here. I tried to use the preventDefault function while closing, and hiding myself the widget, but the problem remains.

If anyone can help me, would be great :)

Sorry for my bad English, Thanks for reading !

[screen scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fkrd.png)

[screen scheduler editing task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iR6t.png)

Comment: Is your dataSource and its transport properly configured? Follow this guide: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud

Comment: My datasource is configured like that : I use a Read method to bind my data from a Model and a Controller. When I was using something like a kendo grid with full editing, I was using only read method and everything was fine. Maybe in the kendo scheduler I MUST do something different as all of theirs others components ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem with the following solution.

I was needing an **Update** function, because it wasn't updating pristine datas when I was saving something (it was saving only in my scheduler.dataSource.data()). I tried to use dataSource.sync() instead of it, but it didn't work.

If someone have a similar problem, be carreful about pristine datas and all would be fine ;)

There is the update function (the easier you can make) :

```
public ActionResult UpdateTachesScheduler([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<PlanningModel> model)
    {
        return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```